# Less painful way to parse a RSS-Feed with lxml?

Tags: python, django, lxml, atom-feed, feedparser

I need to display RSS-feeds with Python, Atom for the most part. Coming from PHP, where I could get values pretty fast with $entry->link i find lxml to be much more precise, faster, albeit complicated. After hours of probing I got this working with the arstechnica-feed:

```
def GetRSSFeed(url):
    out = []
    feed = urllib.urlopen(url)
    feed = etree.parse(feed)
    feed = feed.getroot()
    for element in feed.iterfind(".//item"):
        meta = element.getchildren()
        title = meta[0].text
        link = meta[1].text
        for subel in element.iterfind(".//description"):
            desc = subel.text
            entry = [title,link,desc]
            out.append(entry)
    return out
```

Could this be done any easier? How can I access tags directly? Feedparser gets the job done with one line of code! Why?

Comment: Why are you using lxml instead of feedparser, then?

Answer (score 9):

Look at the feedparser library. It gives you a nicely formatted RSS object.

```
> import feedparser
> feed = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse/')
> print feed.keys()
['feed',
 'status',
 'updated',
 'updated_parsed',
 'encoding',
 'bozo',
 'headers',
 'etag',
 'href',
 'version',
 'entries',
 'namespaces']

>  len(feed.entries)
    30
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i mentioned feedparser in the op. i tested it against lxml, which came out much faster. all i wanna do now is select children by their tag name. like rss.item.description.text. impossible?

Comment: Is this more in line with what you want? (Find all descriptions that are children of items) feed.findall('.//item//description')

Comment: Not an answer to what is being asked . can you do this hard way using lxml

Answer (score 3):

You can try [speedparser](https://github.com/hiidef/speedparser/), an implementation of [Universal Feed Parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/) with `lxml`. Still in beta though.